# Raise_application_error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

В триггере таблицы есть обработка событий, откуда должен срабатывать Raise_application_error(-20000, 'Ошибка!'). На уровне базы, эта ошибка срабатывает всегда, а в Oracle APEX по настроению). Сталкивался ли кто либо с такой ситуацией?
:
`if nvl(p_stage, 0) != count_subtusk then  raise_application_error(-20000, 'Существуют не отработанные задачи!'); end if;`